# How to deal with language repository tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, ambiguous-tags

In addition to tags for languages, like [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), there are also tags for repositories, like [cran](/questions/tagged/cran) and [cpan](/questions/tagged/cpan) respectively. It seems like these tags should not be used for questions about these languages in general, but about specific questions about the use of the repositories (submissions, downloads, etc.). But, they're frequently used as a synonym for the language tag (e.g., a question about general R programming will just be tagged [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [cran](/questions/tagged/cran), essentially redundantly). Should these repository tags just be turned into synonyms? Or should the excerpts explicitly state that they're not for general use?

Some sample data:

- [575 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpan) are tagged [cpan](/questions/tagged/cpan), [559 of which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpan+perl) are also tagged [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)
- [122 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cran) are tagged [cran](/questions/tagged/cran), [122 of which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cran+r) are also tagged [r](/questions/tagged/r)

**UPDATE:**

Examples of correct use of [cran](/questions/tagged/cran):

- [how to check programmatically whether the current installation of R is the newest one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487300/how-to-check-programmatically-whether-the-current-installation-of-r-is-the-newes)
- [R submit to CRAN: which R version to build package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192980/r-submit-to-cran-which-r-version-to-build-package)

Examples of incorrect use of [cran](/questions/tagged/cran):

- [using argmax or something simpler in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252798/using-argmax-or-something-simpler-in-r)
- [R: Time stamps, Unix time and correct usage of 'strptime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308906/r-time-stamps-unix-time-and-correct-usage-of-strptime)

Comment: Just to be clear - is the second *correct* usage of... the *incorrect* one?

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synonyms should only be applied when the two tags mean exactly the same thing.  There are over 28,000 questions tagged [perl](/questions/tagged/perl).  [cpan](/questions/tagged/cpan) is only a subset of that.  Similarly, there are over 32,000 questions tagged [r](/questions/tagged/r).  (Wait, that can't be right.  Hold on.  Yes, there are more questions tagged [r](/questions/tagged/r) than [perl](/questions/tagged/perl).  How did that happen?  Anyway...)  It's fine that all questions tagged [cran](/questions/tagged/cran) are also tagged [r](/questions/tagged/r).  The tag still carries some information, since it tells readers that the question is *more specific* than just R.

---

On correct and incorrect usages of [cpan](/questions/tagged/cpan) and [cran](/questions/tagged/cran):

If a question is about directly using the CPAN or CRAN repositories (e.g., finding, installing, submitting a package), then I'd say it's fine to tag the question with *just* the language and the package name.  If it's about using a package that you installed from a repository, I think it's alright to include the repository tag, but the package name should be included as well.  If there's no discernible connection to the package repository, then the [cpan](/questions/tagged/cpan) or [cran](/questions/tagged/cran) tag should be removed (or not included in the first place).

Comment: That makes sense. But should the tag wiki excerpts be explicit about not being used for general questions? Neither of those tags currently says anything of the sort.

Comment: @Thomas Can you link to some examples of how the tags are being mis-applied?  Are people using `[cran]` on questions that have nothing to do with CRAN at all, for example?

Comment: Yes. Updated with examples of correct/incorrect usage.

Comment: @Thomas It looks like the second pair of links are *incorrect*?  See my edit. If you agree, then you can add something to that effect to the tag wikis.

Comment: "Wait, that can't be right. Hold on. Yes, there are more questions tagged [r] than [perl]. How did that happen?" That's because we aren't migrating enough [r] questions to Stats SE.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes, sorry for the typo. I think your suggestion makes sense.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I see very few non-programming/stats-only in [tag:r]; those that appear get migrated pretty quickly.

Comment: @Thomas: It was a joke :)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn The challenges of humor in print. :) Emoticons save the day.